# Failing validation when trying to create a list with Rspec and FactoryGirl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have a test that is failing due to a

```
Secret#last_five returns the last 5 secrets when last_five is called
 Failure/Error: let!(:secrets){create_list(:secret, 5)}

 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validation failed: Email has already been taken
```

error and I am unsure how to fix it.

Here is the test in secret_spec.rb:

```
describe Secret do
  describe "#last_five" do
    let!(:secrets){create_list(:secret, 5)}
    it "returns the last 5 secrets when last_five is called" do
      expect(Secret.last_five.count).to eq(5)
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the secret_factory.rb:

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :secret do 
    title "Title"
    body "this is the body"
    author
  end

end
```

Here is the user_factory.rb:

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :user, aliases: [:author] do 
    name "Foobar"
    email Faker::Internet.safe_email
    password "password"
    password_confirmation "password"
  end
end
```

I am generating a random email address, and the user factory is the only place I'm using an Email, so I am confused as how I'm getting the Email already taken error.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Not obvious from what you posted. Needs debugging. Rebuild your test database and see if that makes a difference. Find the minimum number of secrets/users that causes the problem. Add a manual validation to user that prints the email that it's complaining about and the emails in the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your are generating a random email **just once**.
You need to execute the `Faker::Internet.safe_email` code, **inside a block**, like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :user, aliases: [:author] do 
    email { Faker::Internet.safe_email }
  end
end
```

As you have defined the factory, `Faker::Internet.safe_email` will be executed on the user's factory definition phase only. Passing a block, a proc will be stored instead of a string. This proc containing the `Faker::Internet.safe_email` will be executed every time you do `create_list(:secret, 5)`, giving you a new fake email each time.

An alternative would be to use [`sequence`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#sequences) method.